# How to index match an array of cells to see if each one will match?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I want an index match (doesn't have to be this formula) to run through an array of these string:

```
black
white
yellow
red
green
blue
light blue
```

to see if they would partial match with any of these cells:

```
black t shirt
white t shirt
yellow t shirt
red t shirt
green t shirt
```

How would I do that?

I've tried:

```
=INDEX(!colors(MATCH(!"*"&{color1,color2,color3,color4}&"*",!tshirts)
```

I want the output to be the color in a column beside the t shirt to indicate a match

```
black - black t shirt
white - white t shirt
red - red t shirt
etc
```

This seems to work, but it's pretty darn janky. I'm looking for cleaner code:

The changing variable here is the color i'm referencing

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP("*"&G2&"*",I3,1,FALSE),IFERROR(VLOOKUP("*"&G3&"*",I3,1,FALSE),IFERROR(VLOOKUP("*"&G4&"*",I3,1,FALSE),IFERROR(VLOOKUP("*"&G5&"*",I3,1,FALSE),IFERROR(VLOOKUP("*"&G6&"*",I3,1,FALSE),IFERROR(VLOOKUP("*"&G7&"*",I3,1,FALSE),IFERROR(VLOOKUP("*"&G8&"*",I3,1,FALSE),"error")))))))
```

Comment: @BigBen I want the output to be the color in a column beside the t shirt to indicate a match

black - black t shirt
white - white t shirt
red - red t shirt
etc

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(""&ROW(C1:C), SUBSTITUTE(REGEXREPLACE(TRIM(
 SPLIT(FLATTEN(QUERY(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(ROW(C1:C)&"♠♣"&IFERROR(TRIM(
 SPLIT(LOWER($C1:$C), " t ", 0, 0))&"♦")), "♣"), 
 "select max(Col2) 
  where Col2 matches '^"&TEXTJOIN("$|^", 1, IF(A1:A="",,LOWER(A1:A)&"♦"))&"$' 
  group by Col2 pivot Col1"),,9^9)), "♠")), "♦$", ), "♦", ","), 2, 0)))
```

[image]

---

or shorter (works only with one color):

```
=INDEX(IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(C1:C, TEXTJOIN("|", 1, SORT(A1:A, 1, 0)))))
```

[image]